# Why does std::expected<T, E> require T to be copy-constructible if it is copy-assignable?

Tags: c++, c++23, std-expected

If we have a type `T` that is not copy-constructible but copy-assignable:

```cpp
struct T {
    T() = default;
    ~T() = default;
    T(const T&) = delete;
    T(T&&) = default;
    T& operator=(const T&) = default;
    T& operator=(T&&) = default;
};
```

then `std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>` is obviously `true`, but `std::is_copy_assignable_v<std::expected<T, int>>` is `false`.

This behavior is described on cppreference: [std::expected<T,E>::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected/operator%3D)

What is the rationale behind this? Why couldn't we allow `std::expected<T, E>` to be copy-assignable if `T` is copy-assignable, even if it is not copy-constructible? The same question also applies to move assignability.

Comment: Because generally you need a T to assign to and you don't necessarily have one. You might have an E. So you need to be able to construct a T, given a T.

Comment: *Why* do you have such a `T`?

Comment: "*If we have a type T that is not copy-constructible but copy-assignable:*" I would argue that such a type is incoherent. To be copy-constructible means that you can create a new object which is an exact duplicate of the original. To be copy-assignable means that you can take an existing object and make it an exact duplicate of the original. So if you can pull off the latter, there is absolutely no reason you can't do the former. What you can do to a live object, you could have done to a not-quite-live one.

Comment: A type could be copy-constructible without being copy-assignable because it has some immutable data that, once initialized, cannot be modified. But for the reverse, there's no real viable justification for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the assignment depends on whether `this->has_value()` is true. We can assign an expected holding a `T` to an expected holding an `E`. In the case of holding an error, there is no "target T" to assign to, and we must copy construct to obtain a value.

Simple illustration:

```
std::expected<char, int> e1 = std::unexpected(2),
                         e2 = {'1'};

e1 = e2; // This copy initializes a char in e1 from the char in e2
```

Since this is all determined at runtime, both conditions must hold for the member to be well-defined on all code paths.

Comment: But especially in this case, where T and E are trivial, isn't it possible to just use the default copy assignment operator? The standard says this operator is deleted instead of defaulted.

Comment: @Voko - I chose fundamental types for exposition purposes. I doubt that's the major use `std::expected` will see. And even if it was possible for us to rely on implicit lifetime in some cases, you are still left with the more general case the library needs to support. You can't ditch those checks entirely, only add more checks before them. Making the condition list long and involved seems like a lot of effort for little gain (this is opinion, if it's wrong it can always be done later to expand std::expected after it was used in the wild).

Comment: @Voko: You cannot copy-assign to an object that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

The `std::expected<T, E>` contains either a `T` object (expected value), or a `E` object (unexpected value).

In a program like this:

```
enum error_code { err1 = 1 };
std::expected<T, error_code> exp = std::unexpected(err1);
exp = T(1);
exp = T(2);
```

It would first create the `exp` object with only a `error_code` (unexpected) inside.

Then `exp = T(1)`, it assigns it so that the `exp` now contains a `T` (expected) value instead. So it destructs the `error_code` object, and then copy-constructs the `T` object (from the one that is passed to it.)
It needs to copy-construct it (instead of copy-assign) because the `T` object in `exp` has not been constructed at this point. (But the `exp` itself is).

In `exp = T(2)`, the `exp` already has a `T` object, so it will instead copy-assign to it.

So because of the first case (when an existing `std::expected<T, E>` that has an unexpected value, it assigned an expected value), copy-assigning is only possible if the `T` object is copy-constructible.